# Malformed url excpetion while trying to run sample spring boot app

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot

I'm trying to run sample Spring Boot application for the first time on Spring Tool Suite 4
Version: 4.8.1.RELEASE and JDK

```
java version "1.8.0_251"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_251-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.251-b08, mixed mode)
```

When try to run sample application as Spring Boot, it gives the following exception

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Djdk.lang.Process.allowAmbiguousCommands=true
Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.net.MalformedURLException: Service URL contains non-ASCII character 0x666
jdk.internal.agent.AgentConfigurationError: java.net.MalformedURLException: Service URL contains non-ASCII character 0x666
    at jdk.management.agent/sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.startRemoteConnectorServer(ConnectorBootstrap.java:493)
    at jdk.management.agent/jdk.internal.agent.Agent.startAgent(Agent.java:447)
    at jdk.management.agent/jdk.internal.agent.Agent.startAgent(Agent.java:599)
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: Service URL contains non-ASCII character 0x666
    at java.management/javax.management.remote.JMXServiceURL.<init>(JMXServiceURL.java:157)
    at jdk.management.agent/sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.exportMBeanServer(ConnectorBootstrap.java:870)
    at jdk.management.agent/sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.startRemoteConnectorServer(ConnectorBootstrap.java:481)
    ... 2 more
```

This the code for the test class

```
package com.apress.ravi;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class UserRegisterationSystemApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UserRegisterationSystemApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

and this is the code for POM.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.apress.ravi</groupId>
    <artifactId>UserRegisterationSystem</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>UserRegisterationSystem</name>
    <description>User Registeration System For Crud Operation</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

usersDTO.java

```
package com.apress.ravi.dto;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="Users")
public class UsersDTO {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        @Column(name = "USER_ID")
        private Long id;

        @Column(name = "NAME")
        private String name;

        @Column(name = "ADDRESS")
        private String address;

        @Column(name = "EMAIL")
        private String email;

        // Getters and Setters methods
}
```

interface UserJpaRepository

```
package com.apress.ravi.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.apress.ravi.dto.UsersDTO;

@Repository
public interface UserJpaRepository extends JpaRepository<UsersDTO, Long> {

        UsersDTO findByName(String name);
}
```

UserRegistrationRestController
package com.apress.ravi.Rest;

```
import java.util.List;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.apress.ravi.dto.UsersDTO;
import com.apress.ravi.repository.UserJpaRepository;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/user")
public class UserRegistrationRestController {
        public static final Logger logger =
                LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserRegistrationRestController.class);

        private UserJpaRepository userJpaRepository;

        @Autowired
        public void setUserJpaRepository(UserJpaRepository userJpaRepository) {
                this.userJpaRepository = userJpaRepository;
        }        
        
        @GetMapping("/")
        public ResponseEntity<List<UsersDTO>> listAllUsers() {
                List<UsersDTO> users = userJpaRepository.findAll();
                return new ResponseEntity<List<UsersDTO>>(users, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
}
```

UserRegisterationSystemApplicationTests
package com.apress.ravi;

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@SpringBootTest
class UserRegisterationSystemApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

Comment: you have a problem with your application code, but you have not posted your application code. The error message is super clear `java.net.MalformedURLException: Service URL contains non-ASCII character 0x666
    at java.management/javax.management.remote.JMXServiceURL.<init>(JMXServiceURL.java:157)` voted to close

Comment: The Thrown Exception is at java.management/javax.management.remote.JMXServiceURL 
Which it is a class i didn't write !
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/management/remote/JMXServiceURL.html

Comment: but you are using JMX somewhere in your application, and you are defining a URL somewhere in your application that is CLEARLY malformed. You do know that code doesnt automatically use itself?

Comment: post enough code so that we can replicate and run your application and get the same exception. Because you have not posted anything

Comment: Ok , will update the post with all classes

Comment: please, do add application.properties!

Comment: Application.properties is empty file !

Answer (score 0):

It might be that the host name of your computer contains a non-ascii char which spring is using in the JMX URL.
Disable JMX monitoring if you don't need it using the following property

```
spring.jmx.enabled=false
```

Comment: I've added this property to application,properties file , and tried 
the same error happened , 
also application.properties shows a warinign endpoints.jmx.enabled is an unknown property

Comment: I just changed that, it is 'spring.jmx.enabled'

Comment: also same error happened , my host name is : OSMOHAME-EG

Comment: I checked the character referred in the exception; it is ٦ (digit six in ARABIC-INDIC), could your windows be set to show numbers in non English format

Comment: This changed the error from 0x666 to 0x665